# Changing mind about upvoting a comment

Tags: support, comments, voting

If I change my mind about upvoting a comment, is there any way to cancel my upvote there?

Comment: Just click on the arrow once more (but beware there’s a timeout).

Comment: If you cancel the upvote, you cannot upvote again. And canceling is only possible within a narrow time window (a minute?). If you can no longer remove your vote and think it would be important to do so, add another comment instead and explain what is wrong with the other one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a meta stackexchange thread on this topic, here: [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment). In brief, you *can* change your mind -- "upvoting" again undoes the upvote -- provided that you do it quickly (within 60 seconds) and without navigating away from the page. Otherwise, no, you can't take it back as far as I'm aware.

It would be nice to not have to decide quickly, but I think the SE philosophy is that comments are not supposed to be important and should be used only for improving posts; thus upvoting comments is considered also low on the significance scale. (In practice at MO, it feels a little different to me, but there you have it.)

Comment: I see. Still 60 seconds... I mean, I have 5 minutes to edit my comment, why only 1 minute to, say, notice an accidental click to undo it? But this question has obviously nothing to do with your clarifying answer, thanks!

Comment: Depending on what the comment says, on MO a comment upvote often means "this comment is mathematically correct". As one may find an error a considerable time later and as a wrong comment with many upvotes is likely to confuse readers, I think it would be helpful to allow withdrawing a comment upvote also after 60 seconds have passed.

Comment: @StefanKohl Only saw your comment now. Quite convincing!